# MobileFirst Operation Analytics Console - Not linked to MobileFirst Admin Operational Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

I followed the below URL to configure my Operation Analytics Console.

[IBM InfoCenter Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_analytics_properties.html)

Configured the properties in the Project WorkLight Runtime Application deployed in WAS. But i am not able to find the property wl.analytics.console.url under the environment variable for the web module section in WAS admin.

Please guide me, Were to add this property. And how to enable Operation Admin Console to link to Operation Analytics.

MobileFirst Foundation Platform Server 7.0 Consumer Edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what version of MobileFirst Platform Foundation you are using - for purposes of this answer, I am assuming 7.0.  The way you set the JNDI properties on WAS is illustrated [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html).  If you are in the "Environment entries for Web modules" section, you're in the right place already.

You should first set the "wl.analytics.url" JNDI property.  Once you set this (to point to your Operational Analytics server), and restart WAS, your application will begin forwarding data to Operational Analytics.

If you've protected the Analytics data entry point, you should also set the "wl.analytics.username" and "wl.analytics.password" properties appropriately.

There is a problem on full-profile WAS where the "wl.analytics.console.url" property can't be edited from the WAS admin console.  We have a bug open on this.  Until that is fixed, you can use this workaround to set the property:

You will need to update the file "WEBSPHERE_PATH/AppServer/profiles/YOUR_PROFILE/installedApps/YOUR_NODE_CELL/MOBILEFIRST.EAR/MOBILEFIRST.WAR/WEB-INF/classes/conf/worklight.properties" (where the things in all caps are placeholders for whatever the correct value for your environment is - except for "WEB-INF", which is literal...). Inside this worklight.properties file, add the "wl.analytics.console.url" property, with the correct URL for your environment. Then restart the server.  This workaround is only necessary for full-profile WAS, and is not necessary for (nor is it applicable to) Liberty Profile or Tomcat.

After performing these steps, you should then see the link to the Operational Analytics Console page in the MobileFirst Operations Console.

I note that the "wl.analytics.console.url" property is not mentioned in the page I linked above.  Looking at the feedback that was posted on that page, it seems that this has already been raised as an issue, and is being investigated.

Comment: Thanks Pat. I set the wl.analytics.url as http://<hostname>:<port>/<context-root>/data. Protected the analytics data entry point means, I have mapped the user group to Operational Analytics Console. Do i need to set the admin username and password for the same in JNDI right?

Comment: To protect the entry point, you set up the security roles (as defined here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/t_securing_op_analytics.html) and then set the "wl.analytics.username" and "wl,analytics.password" properties to be the same as the username and password you're using.  So, yes, if I'm interpreting your question correctly, your understanding is correct.  :-)

Comment: Perfect. I set those credentials and restarted the server. Still its not showing the link in Operational Admin console for the application. Are we missing any other settings?

Comment: I do remember, in MobileFirst 6.3 there is a property wl.analytics.queue.size which need to be set to 1, so that it will start showing the data immediately. I do see somewhere in the 7.0 documentation that WLREPORT database is deprecated and Operational Analytics will take care of that. But in Project WAR file deployment documentation, its say we need to create two databases such as WRKLGHT and WLREPORT for the Project runtime. Is this something case the issue.?

Comment: You can set the queue size to 1 if you do want the data to always be sent immediately, if that's appropriate for your environment (or if you're testing, etc.).  WLREPORT is deprecated, but you still do need to create the database (and our tooling does this for your automatically when you deploy an app).  But if you don't set "reports.exportRawData" to be "true", it won't be used - but, this should not cause the problem you're seeing, whether it's used or not.

Comment: I see that we actually have a bug open on the missing "wl.analytics.console.url" property.  I'm trying to find out if there's a workaround for you to set this property in full-profile WAS without having to take apart the WAR file and edit the "web.xml" file by hand.

Comment: I have a possible workaround for you to try - one of our devs is still verifying this, but if you want to try first - in the WAS admin console, instead of going to "Environment entries for Web modules", go to "Manage Modules".  Click on the application module, then go to "Custom Properties".  Add the "wl.analytics.console.url" property, with the value being the Analytics console URL.  Then restart.  If that works for you, I'll edit my answer to reflect it; if not, there's another workaround I can provide that isn't quite as clean, but should definitely work....

Comment: Thanks Pat, I tried the same. Its not working. I have to give the Public URL or internal access url of WAS01 and WAS02 for the same in ClusterMembers JVM process definition property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78244/discussion-between-pvr-and-patbarron).